# Jquery toggle() and highlight() not working in rails 3 call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a form that is submitted via ajax in a rails 3 app. The form works, the record is updated, but the jquery code in update.js.erb is not working. It is simply:

```
$('#item').toggle().highlight();
```

I get a ".toggle().highlight(); is not a function" error in firebug

I recently upgraded from rails 2.3.8 to rails 3, and I think this was working before.

Do I need to included jquery and jquery.ui again in the update.js.erb template?

---

Update

It turns out I need to change `.highlight();` to `.effect("highlight", {}, 3000);` and it now works

Comment: @eveevans has a nice answer, but yes be sure to include the jquery libraries.

Comment: thks MrDanA,
and deb, you have to include jQuery library only once, if you included it in the header that's ok, you don't have to include it again in the update.js.erb   ( but make sure you are included it ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using only jQuery? or are you calling to prototype, in that case you have to include jquery with compatible mode, and call it like:

```
jQuery('#item').toggle().highlight();
```

Comment: I'm using only jquery (gem "jquery-rails")

Comment: ok , mm did you active respond_to js? in the update controller?

Comment: gem is only there to get the latest jquery-rails adapter in you project, you still have to include jquery and rails adapter in application layout. Read more at https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

Comment: @gupta the gem adds all the necessary files to :defaults,  they are included in the application layout. No javascript errors anywhere else, everything else works, it's just the update.js.erb

Comment: @eveevans yep, I added js to the respond_to block in the controller

Comment: Are you completely sure that your js code is running in the update? , try with some alert();

Comment: I changed .highlight(); to .effect("highlight", {}, 3000); and it works